# Error while using Microsoft Translator API from console app

Tags: c#, wcf, console-application, microsoft-translator

I am trying to consume Microsoft Translator API by using the SOAP service exposed by them
**http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V1/SOAP.svc** , by adding service reference in a console app and have tried calling **Detect** method but its failing with the below error

```
ServiceReference1.LanguageServiceClient client = new LanguageServiceClient();
                string detect = client.Detect("", "Hello");
                Console.WriteLine("Detected language "+detect.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
```

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: IP cannot access the service
>   temporarily
>
> Server stack trace:    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRunt
>   ime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean on eway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan tim eout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCall
>   Message methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   req Msg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgDa ta, Int32 type)    at
>   ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.LanguageService.Detect(String
>   appId,  String text)    at
>   ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.LanguageServiceClient.Detect(String
>   appId, String text) in C:\Users\lh95\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Conso leApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Service
>   References\ServiceReference1\Referenc e.cs:line 69    at
>   ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\lh95\documents \visual studio
>   2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs: line
>   25
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: IP cannot
>   access the se rvice temporarily
>
> Server stack trace:    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRunt
>   ime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean on eway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan tim eout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCall
>   Message methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   req Msg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgDa ta, Int32 type)    at
>   ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.LanguageService.Detect(String
>   appId,  String text)    at
>   ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.LanguageServiceClient.Detect(String
>   appId, String text) in C:\Users\lh95\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Conso leApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Service
>   References\ServiceReference1\Referenc e.cs:line 69    at
>   ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\lh95\documents \visual studio
>   2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs: line
>   33

Answer (score 0):

That is a message (well, exception) returned by the server; you'll need to check the documentation for any cases in which it would refuse to serve requests. You may be temporarily disallowed from accessing the service, for example, if you made too many requests in a very short timespan or something similar - that's what it sounds like to me. Or that they somehow think you've been trying to do things against their terms of service.